# Spring cloud stream confluent schema registry not working

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Below code is not working with confluent schema registry. its not giving connection timeout errors with schema registry url.

**consumer configuration**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
public class ConsumerApplication {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void process(Sensor data) {
        logger.info(data);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class ConfluentSchemaRegistryConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient(@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}") String endpoint){
            ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient client = new ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient();
            client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8081");
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

configuration looks like this

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: sensor-topic
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8081
      schema:
        avro:
          schema-locations: classpath:avro/sensor.avsc
server.port: 9999
```

**producer configuration**

below is the producer configuration to place the message and its not able to connect to schema registry

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          contentType: application/*+avro
          destination: sensor-topic
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8081
      schema:
        avro:
          schema-locations: classpath:avro/sensor.avsc
server.port: 9009
```

below is the producer configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
@RestController
public class Producer1Application {

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    private Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Producer1Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/messages", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendMessage() {
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(randomSensor()).build());
        return "ok, have fun with v1 payload!";
    }

    private Sensor randomSensor() {
        Sensor sensor = new Sensor();
        sensor.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "-v1");
        sensor.setAcceleration(random.nextFloat() * 10);
        sensor.setVelocity(random.nextFloat() * 100);
        sensor.setTemperature(random.nextFloat() * 50);
        return sensor;
    }

    //Another convenience POST method for testing deterministic values
    @RequestMapping(value = "/messagesX", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendMessageX(@RequestParam(value="id") String id, @RequestParam(value="acceleration") float acceleartion,
                               @RequestParam(value="velocity") float velocity, @RequestParam(value="temperature") float temperature) {
        Sensor sensor = new Sensor();
        sensor.setId(id + "-v1");
        sensor.setAcceleration(acceleartion);
        sensor.setVelocity(velocity);
        sensor.setTemperature(temperature);
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(sensor).build());
        return "ok, have fun with v1 payload!";
    }

    @Configuration
    static class ConfluentSchemaRegistryConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient(@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}") String endpoint){
            ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient client = new ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient();
            client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run the sample here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/schema-registry-samples/schema-registry-confluent

Did you follow the instructions on the README? We tested that sample against Schema Registry server 4.0 and it works. Do you have any further stracktrace or error messages?

Comment: I also tested above sample with latest confluent and it worked for me. Check if your schema registry server is running at port 8081